# Is there an American term for a group of elitist schools, similar to the abbreviation “Oxbridge”?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, abbreviations, portmanteau-words

I saw the word, ‘Oxbridge’, a portmanteau of Oxford and Cambridge, in a comment to [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93260)  asking for a better word for ‘invigilator’:

> Whereas the situation is reversed in the UK, and one in a thousand would recognize *proctor* -- although even the one in a thousand would be the one who went to **Oxbridge** and would give it a different meaning altogether.

We have the abbreviation “東大一ツ橋” (Todaihitotsubashi) combining the names of Tokyo University and Hitotsubashi University, both national universities, as a symbolic phrase  of elitist schools, though I don’t know why Hitotsubashi University singly skewed to economics was paired to Tokyo University out of 783 universities and colleges (in 2012) in Japan.

In the sports area, we have the word “早慶” (Sohkei), an abbreviated combination of Waseda University and Keio University, both private universities excelling in baseball, rugby, soccer and many other sports, as well as in academic achievement.

Is there an American counterpart of “Oxbridge”, “Sohkei”  and “Todaihitotsubashi,” or does “Yale-Harvard” suffice?

Comment: There's no two-school blend, really; probably the closest thing, suggesting age (or as much age as we've gt), prestige, social and academic superiority, and access to power, would be *Ivy League*. But the Ivies don't have the clout they once had.

Comment: When referring to the group we usually just call them *ivy-league* schools.  "although even the one-in-a-thousand would be the one who went to an *ivy-league* school..."

Comment: Are you referring to Princetard?

Comment: _Harvard/Yale_ is the two-school solution. But there's no _Oxbridge_ portmanteau.

Comment: @Mitch. I don’t find the word, ‘Princetard’ in dictionaries. What does it mean? Princeton graduate?

Comment: I think that "Ivy League" is the closest semantic if not morphological equiv

Comment: @YoichiOishi He was making a portmanteau of "Princeton" and "Harvard" as a joke. He made it up from two Ivy League colleges in the US

Comment: One other side note: While Harvard/Yale would likely dominate the academic landscape in areas like law and political science, one might argue that, in engineering, the U.S. triumvirate might be CalTech/Stanford/M.I.T.

Comment: I have no real opinion on which particular two *are* at the top. Most likely the *Harvard/Yale* pairing wouldn't actually come top in many lists (they're 2nd and 11th in this one from [The Times](http://www.timeshighereducation.co.uk/world-university-rankings/2011-12/world-ranking/region/north-america)). But they are the two I think I most often hear paired up in common parlance.

Comment: @J.R.: CalTech/MIT only ~ Harvard/Yale. Stanford is more like Princeton, right down to an Institute for Advanced Study.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Actually Harvard and Yale are the top US private universities, and are always in any excellence-centered top ten, usually at the top. Chicago, Berkeley, Michigan, UCLA, Stanford, Texas, OSU, and Penn State are perennial decimates, as well; at this level it varies by area (science, social science, CL/AI, etc.).

Comment: @John Lawler: We're well outside my sphere of competence here. All I know is the California Institute of Technology and MIT (and JPL) are associated in my mind with "leading edge" (I don't even know why the first one isn't normally CIT). But I do think of Harvard/Yale as the archetypal (or at least, most famous) "prestigious/long-established" institutions across the pond. That's definitely *not* based on any specific knowledge of any of them - it's just a matter of what associations the names have for me.

Comment: @Simchona. I didn’t come to the thought of “Princet(on)＋(Harv)erd.” I thought it’s a joke for “Princet(on)＋(Bas)tard. No offense meant to 'Princetoners'.

Comment: ...on reflection, maybe I shouldn't have included *(historically speaking)* in reference to the Harvard/Yale pair. That's entirely down to my perception that they're often portrayed in popular culture (movies, etc.) as being somewhat behind the times in "social" terms (i.e. - elitist). Which isn't likely to bear any relation to "real-world truth".

Comment: @JohnLawler: I knew I was opening a can of worms there... :^) anyway, it depends on [who you ask](http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges/rankings/engineering). (And, yes, I realize those rankings don't mean [everything](http://www.ajc.com/news/news/local/surveys-shape-influential-college-rankings/nR7dH/).) My main point, though, was to point out how different subcommunities might have their own version of what their "Oxbridge" is.

Comment: minor detail but pet peeve...it's "Caltech", not "CalTech".

Comment: FYI, you can also get the best of Ivy League and Oxbridge at [Ivy Bridge](http://www.ivybridge.com/).

Comment: My apologies, I commented too quickly. The minor joke has many parts: Harvard and Princeton are not considered rivals but they probably consider themselves better than the other; the pair was chosen purely for the sound (as someone pointed out, portmanteaux with other schools just don't sound good); the '-tard' ending is more reminiscent of 'retard' an epithet for the less intellectually inclined. Since the two (along with many other elite colleges) are in fact elite intellectually, there is no Wodehousian humor in the valet being more capable than the gentleman.

Comment: Equivalent term for Australia: [Sandstone universities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandstone_universities)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm going to omit any caveats and disclaimers, and say that yes, there is an American equivalent of *Oxbridge*, and it's ***[ivy league](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/Ivy%20League)***. Yes, there are elite colleges in the US that are not traditionally part of the Ivy League, but they can still be described as *ivy league* (lowercase/adjectival form); and the US is a larger place than the UK (or Japan, for that matter), so it stands to reason that our equivalent of Oxbridge would include a larger group of institutions.

If you really want to restrict your expression to two institutions, that would be *Harvard/Yale*, which doesn't really lend itself to a portmanteau word. (Haryale? Yalevard? You see the problem.)

Comment: What does this add to the answer I posted earlier?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you said that "there's no direct US equivalent to Oxbridge". I disagree: if you don't care about the number, the direct equivalent is *ivy league*, and if you do care, it's *Harvard/Yale*. No, neither is a portmanteau, but their function is the same as *Oxbridge*.

Comment: It's not a combination of two names, but on many internet forums HYP (or sometimes HYPS) is used to refer to Harvard-Yale-Princeton (or Harvard-Yale-Princeton-Stanford) in much the same way that one would use Oxbridge.

Comment: Schools that compete for students with the traditional Ivy League schools are even called the "new ivies": http://www.unigo.com/Rankings/RankingDetails.aspx?RankingId=27&Ordinal=10&Year=2013, http://georgetown.patch.com/articles/georgetown-makes-list-of-top-10-new-ivies

Comment: Harpur College, the arts and sciences component of the Binghamton component of the State University of New York, was long ago christened as one of a select number of so-called "public ivies"--each comparable in size and quality to the eight elite private colleges that make up the official Ivy League.

Answer (score 6):

"Oxbridge" is well-known across the entire world, but we do also have [Redbrick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_brick_university) universities.

Note that "Redbrick" was originally a somewhat derogatory term distinguishing six "newer" universities from the seven [ancient universities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_universities) which were all established several centuries earlier. But today many people use "Redbrick" for any of the top dozen or more British universities.

Per comments, there's no direct US equivalent to Oxbridge, partly because it's not so easy to agree on the *two and only two* top universities (although as John Lawler says, *Harvard/Yale* must be a strong contender historically speaking). The nearest equivalent is probably...

> [Ivy League](http://etcweb.princeton.edu/CampusWWW/Companion/ivy_league.html) - the name generally applied to eight universities (Brown, Columbia, Cornell, Dartmouth, Harvard, Pennsylvania, Princeton, and Yale) that over the years have had common interests in scholarship as well as in athletics.
>
> Stanley Woodward, New York Herald Tribune sports writer, coined the phrase in the early thirties.

Obviously "Oxbridge" specifically represents *the top two* in the UK, and I don't think anyone would refer to either Oxford or Cambridge as a Redbrick. But to Brits at least, *Ivy League* usually means something pretty much equivalent to *Oxbridge **plus** the Redbricks*.